# removeEventListener not executing or working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why my removeEventListener is not working, I have tried multiple things to fix it but still not working any insight would be helpful. addEventListener is working as intended but the issue arises when i try to remove listener. Below is the snippet of the code in question. Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

```
init: function(el, callback) {
     var that = this;
     this.touchSurface = el;
     this.touchSurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){ that.onStart(e); }, false);
     this.touchSurface.removeEventListener('touchstart',function(e){ that.onStart(e); }, false);
},

onStart: function(e) {
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: Why are you removing event just below add?

Comment: My bad I have not included entire code, but after adding addEvent listener I do certain DOM manipulation before trying to removeEventListener

Comment: But if you're adding and removing in the same sequential execution of code (no matter how much intervening code), there's never a chance for the event to actually be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you remove an eventListener, you must pass the actual same function reference.  You are passing a different function (that has the same code, but a different function).

The way to solve this is to put the callback into its own function and then you can reference that exact same function in both `.addEventListener()` and `.removeEventListener()`.

---

I'm not sure why you're trying to add and then remove an event listener immediately after one another (as there is no benefit to doing so), but you could do so like this:

```
init: function(el, callback) {
     var that = this;

     function handleStart(e) {
         that.onStart(e);
     }


     this.touchSurface = el;
     el.addEventListener('touchstart', handleStart), false);
     el.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleStart, false);
},
```

FYI, there doesn't appear to be any use to installing an event handler and then removing it like this in the same sequential execution of code, no matter how much intervening code there is because there's no opportunity for the event to actually be processed.

Comment: The issue was that I wasn't passing the same reference even though the code was same. Thanks to jfriend00 for pointing this out.